# Libgdx ScreenViewport resize() when reducing window size on desktop

Tags: libgdx

Libgdx desktop build. Trying resizing window using ScreenVieport. Non-continous rendering. It seems resize() handler gets called instantly only when window expands.

When I reduce window resize() is called not immediatelly, but only after mouse enters window's space. Is it a common behaviour? Any walkaround?

Comment: Does this happen when you try to resize the window in all directions?

Comment: when I reduce window size - yes. tried all 8 possible variants: 4 corners and 4 borders.